# How to add Admob non-rewarded video ads in Swift

Tags: swift, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, video-ads

I implemented an iOS and displayed video ads on app. I decided to use Google Mobile Ads due to its popular.

The problem is it only provides Rewarded Video Ads. It means when the video is playing and user close it, it always show a popup warning that if user closes ads, he won't receive reward.

[image: The alert popup when user closes the video ads]

My desire is simpler, I just want to show video ads to monetize and user can close it without the alert popup like many other game apps did. They just show video ads between changing scene or on game over scene,...

I temporarily use the rewarded video ads, but now Google AdMob claims that my implementation is violent with their policy

[image: The violation description from Admob]

I did search solutions, but no hope to find normal video ads option. How can other game apps do this and do they use an alternative Ads provider?

Comment: use https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial or banner ads.

Comment: I used to add banner and interstitial ads but I wanna add video ads and I wonder why other game did it

Comment: when you login into your admob account. Goto Interstitial ads and uncheck "Text, image, and rich media" and check "video". So your interstitial ad will only show video ads. Which users can easily close

Comment: Wow, awesome, let me try. Thank you so much @AmodGokhale . I think you can make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interstitial ad https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

[image]

Login to admob account. Select Interstitial ad and then only select Video ( if you want to display only video advertisements )